# Prove that the set of all diagonal matrices is a subring of $\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$ which is isomorphic to $R \times\dots\times R$ ($n$ factors)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Can someone tell me, is that diagonal matrices is a subring of $\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$ which is (ring) isomorphic to $R \times · · · \times R$ (n factors) and why?.

Comment: Do you at least see that it is a sub ring??? forget about isomorphism and all.. do you see any obvious map between set of all diagonal matrices in $M_n(R)$ and all elements in $R\times R\times...\times R$ (n factors)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try the map

$$\phi:Diag(R)\to R^n\;,\;\;\;\phi\begin{pmatrix}a_1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&a_2&0&\ldots&0\\...&...&...&...&...\\0&0&0&\ldots&a_n\end{pmatrix}:=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$$

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio for your HINT..

Answer (score 3):

Hints for the first part: are $0\in \operatorname{Mat_n}(R)$ and the identity $1\in \operatorname{Mat_n}(R)$  diagonal matrices? What is the sum of any 2 diagonal matrices? What is  the product (consider the usual product of matrices) of any 2 diag. matrices? After these checks, please consider DonAntonio's answer for the second part.

Comment: Thanks @Avitus for your HINT..