# Identifying Particular Matrix Ring

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, linear-groups

In the course of a big perturbation calculation I was doing, a particular matrix ring kept popping up, whose nice properties were essential to being able to complete the calculation. As such, I've become curious what this group is, and what else is known about it.

The ring consists of all matrices of the form $$a I + b N$$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $a\neq 0$, $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and $N$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all ones.
A few basic facts I've worked out about such matrices:

- $(a I + b N)(c I +d N)= acI + (bc+ad+bd n)N$, which is true because $N^2 = nN$.
- $\det(a I +b N)=a^{n-1}(a+bn)$. This fact can then easily be used to compute the eigenvalues of $aI+bN$.
- $(aI+bN)^{-1}=\frac{1}{nab+a^2}\left( (a+nb)I-bN \right )$ so long as $a \neq -nb$.
- The ring is commutative.

Given that these matrices are so computationally tractable, I feel like they must have been studied, and must have a name. Does anybody know what this ring is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The multiplication is commutative, so if we have a group, then it is a known abelian group. However, there is a problem with the determinant, for the case that $a+bn=0$. So this isn't a group under multiplication, because not all matrices from the set are invertible, e.g., the ones with $b=-a/n$.

Comment: You're absolutely right - I've rephrased to avoid calling it a group. (It is at least a ring, with some elements being invertible.)

Comment: I usually diagonalise $N$: one entry $n$ all others $0$. So wrt the new basis $aI+bN$ just becomes $diag (a+nb, a,a,\dots, a)$. I've never thought there was a special name.

Comment: There is a name for the subring of diagonal matrices in the ring $M_n(R)$, at least -see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486369/prove-that-the-set-of-all-diagonal-matrices-is-a-subring-of-operatornamemat). It is called $R\times \cdots \times R$. In your case it would be isomorphic to $R\times R$.

Comment: Well, if the scalar field is $k$ then the ring is isomorphic to $k[x] / \langle x^2 - nx \rangle$.  I don't know of any name for that particular form of quotient ring.  Also assuming $n \ne 0$ in $k$, then the Chinese remainder theorem gives that the ring is further isomorphic to $(k[x] / \langle x \rangle) \times (k[x] / \langle x-n \rangle) \simeq k \times k$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to see the isomorphism with $k[x]/\langle x^2 -n x \rangle$? It is the case that $N^2 = n N$, but it is not in general the case that $(a I + b N)^2 = n (a I + b N)$.

Comment: It's clear that $I$ and $N$ generate your $\mathbb R$-algebra, and that there is clearly a homomorphism $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-nx)$ onto it.  They are both two dimensional, though, so it's an isomorphism.  You can just think of $x$ as what you previously called $N$: the isomorphism is given by $x+(x^2-nx)\mapsto N$, and $1+(x^2-nx)\mapsto 1$.

Comment: I see, thank you!